# DB2 how to gather the statistics automatically on all tables of a schema?

Tags: database, db2

Is there an easier way to gather the DB2 statistics for ALL the tables of a schema in DB2.

I do this in two steps currently:

Generate the list of all the table names in a schema.

Then do the following for each table:

```
RUNSTATS ON TABLE schema.table AND INDEXES ALL
```

DB2 Version 9.7 on LUW

Comment: The answer depends on information you failed to give. Which Db2 version, and which operating-system ?  Edit your question to give those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Db2 LUW V9.7 if you insist on scripted runstats then you must generate the list of objects and then runstats those objects. This is easy to script. Sometimes it's better to let Db2 to the runstats via auto_runstats.

There's also a side effect of the REORGCHK command, it allows a syntax  '`db2 reorgchk update statistics on schema X'`  (although you might not want to use this).

For auto runstats, It may be smarter to allow each table to have an optional runstats-profile, and to define (via XML) the time-window when you want runstats to operate, and use the stored procedures AUTOMAINT_SET_POLICY or AUTOMAINT_SET_POLICYFILE , and let Db2 do the work for you. For many use-cases this is optimal (especially when databases are growing and the ability to have table-specific profiles becomes invaluable), but not all.

Comment: Thanks Mao for the answer.